# sqlite group by statement

Tags: sqlite

I have a table with about 200 records, each record has a date, adzone, revenue, clicks, cpm.

What is the proper sqlite statement total count of how many records where grouped in the same statement?

```
select SUM(revenue), SUM(clicks), adzone
  from mytable
  where date='12345'
  group by adzone
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `COUNT(1)` column:

```
select SUM(revenue), SUM(clicks), adzone, COUNT(1)
  from mytable
 where date='12345'
 group by adzone
```